# How to group in mongo db on dynamic attributes with the aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using the following schema from the mongodb [FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#how-can-i-effectively-use-indexes-strategy-for-attribute-lookups):

```
{
  attrib : [
        { k: "color", v: "red" },
        { k: "shape", v: "rectangle" },
        { k: "color", v: "blue" },
        { k: "avail", v: true }
       ]
}
```

How can I group and count the collection e.g. by "color"? I would prefer using the aggregation framework if possible instead of map reduce.

My result should look like this:

```
[
    {
        v: "blue",
        count: 5
    },
    {
        v: "red",
        count: 2
    },
    {
        v: "black",
        count: 52
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you be a little bit more descriptive on which documents you have as input and what you expect as output?

Comment: If you just want to count the documents, try `.find({"attrib.k": "color"}).count()`. If you want something more complex such as occurance count within the documents, please provide more information, such as expected output :)

Comment: I've just added my expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly trivial, we need to do an unwind, match, and then a group by:

```
db.so.aggregate( [
    { $unwind : '$attrib' },
    { $match: { 'attrib.k' : 'color' } },
    { $group: { _id: '$attrib.v', count: { '$sum': 1 } } }
] );
```

Unwind blows up the "attrib" array into one document per array element:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51eeb9f2812db9ff4412f132"),
            "attrib" : {
                "k" : "color",
                "v" : "red"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51eeb9f2812db9ff4412f132"),
            "attrib" : {
                "k" : "shape",
                "v" : "rectangle"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51eeb9f2812db9ff4412f132"),
            "attrib" : {
                "k" : "color",
                "v" : "blue"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51eeb9f2812db9ff4412f132"),
            "attrib" : {
                "k" : "avail",
                "v" : true
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Match then removes all the non color items:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51eeb9f2812db9ff4412f132"),
            "attrib" : {
                "k" : "color",
                "v" : "red"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51eeb9f2812db9ff4412f132"),
            "attrib" : {
                "k" : "color",
                "v" : "blue"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

And the group finally makes it return:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "blue",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "red",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

(All above output is just from you single sample document)

Comment: Thanks! Do you think, that using the aggregation framework is better/faster than using map/reduce for this?

Comment: Yes, as it doesn't go into JavaScript that way.

Comment: One further question: How to include/group also the objects, where the color attribute doesn't exist at all?

Comment: I can't think of a quick way there as a full object is no longer there to do the full grouping on... let me steam on that!

Comment: Did you found a solution for this or do you have an advice how to handle this? Do I have to make two queries and merge the result in my backend code?